# Need to hide many field columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Here I have an excel file that I have has a lot of the fields column. I wish to hide some of the fields and show a few columns to perform chart type. How do I do that ?

I do know how to do it but is there a way around that can I pull something and enable checkbox to hide the columns ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?  What do you already know how to do?  How is that inadequate?  Describe the nature and location of the checkboxes you're talking about.  How would they be visible when the column is hidden?

Comment: What i am trying to say here is what if you have so many fields columns and you want to hide them. I know how to hide then by right click and hit hide...but what about so many that are too many all the way to the right of the MS Excel ?

Comment: You can select a large range of columns at one time and hide them all with a single right-click hide, you don't need to do them individually.